# Redirect after Transition using Workflow Script for Dexterity content types

Tags: plone, dexterity

I have a Dexterity content type and after I change its state or transition it to another state,I want the page to redirect to a specified URL. So I added a script on the workflow, and trigger it after the transition. After I test it nothing happens, it stays on the current content.

Here's my script with parameter list - state_change:

```
request = container.REQUEST
response = request.response
response.redirect(some_url)
```

Is there any problem with my script?

Comment: My guess is that your workflow script is never being executed. As a diagnostic, try introducing code that will cause an exception on execution.

Comment: I tried introducing code like import pdb. The code gets read, since it raises an error.

Comment: This might happen if something else later in the stack rewrites response again, but I really don't know what could do such ugly thing and the code should just work. You can debug this by installing a post-publication hook through addon and see the contents of HTTP response object before it gets send down to the browser.